# To run unit tests and integrate JaCoCo with Android framework code compiled using Makefile

Tags: android, makefile, jacoco

I want to do statistics on Android framework code coverage and test cases.
I tried to use Jacoco's Java Agent but failed.

```shell
# jacoco-0.8.8.zip

$ unzip jacoco-0.8.8.zip

$ java -javaagent:./jacocoagent.jar=includes=*,output=tcpserver,port=9000,address=localhost,append=true -jar ~/project/target/test.jar

$ java -jar ./jacococli.jar dump --address localhost --port 9000--destfile jacoco.exec

$ java -jar ./jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles ~/project/target/classes --sourcefiles ~/project/src/main/java --html ./report
```